# how to 'bake' parameters into click() call jquery?

Tags: jquery

I've got an ajax call that collects XML, and based on that data creates a number of divs on which I attach click() jquery listeners.  When clicked, I want those divs to call a function and to pass a parameter into that function.  However, by the time the click is called the value of the parameter has changed.  Here's an example from a [jsfiddle I built](http://jsfiddle.net/snTEf/1/) to demonstrate the problem:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    function x() {

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/xml/",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: {
            xml: "<the>xml</the>"
        },
        success: function(xml) { 
          console.log('success');                

          $('#test').show(); 

          var text = "CORRECT";      

          $('#test').click(function() {

            insertText(text);
            console.log(text);
          });

          text = "WRONG";

        }        
      });
    }

    x();

  });

  function insertText(t) {

      $('#test').html(t);
  }
```

I want the text to show up as CORRECT, not WRONG.

​I know this is a bit of a convoluted example but I'm trying to simulate my actual code as much as possible in terms of scope and what is going on.  By the time the `click()` function gets called based on a click, the value of `text` has changed.  Is there some way to 'bake' the value of `text` into the `click()` call at the time I create it?  I'll be creating a number of these through a `for` loop as it runs through the XML and don't want to hang on to all that data into variables for use later.

Comment: The click handler will always show the text variable with a value as wrong, this is because you can't possibly click it fast enough before you have changed the value of text. I don't understand why you need to do it this way.

Comment: i should have added more of the structure for my example.  this click binding code exists within a for() loop that runs through all named elements of an XML document, binding clicks with associated parms based on IDs.  IOW, it creates a number of divs, each with click() functions that need to know a parm that was gathered at the time the div was created/set during the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to create a function that attaches the handler.  In this way, the parameter within the function is unchanged.

```
      var text = "CORRECT";      

      bindClick("test", text);


      // ...

      function bindClick(id, text){

          $('#' + id).click(function() {
            insertText(text);
            console.log(text);
          });
      }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/snTEf/2/

Answer (score 1):

Like this -- you bind it to a local variable in a closure form.

```
(function(text){
     $('#test').click(function() {
            insertText(text);
            console.log(text);
      });
})(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `click` function isn't called until after the `text = "WRONG"` assignment gets called, so of course the function uses the "incorrect" value of `text`.  If you want to, as you say, bake the value of `text` into your function at definition time, you can use an immediately-invoked anonymous function like so:

```
(function(bakedText) {
  $('#test').click( function() {
    insertText(bakedText);
    console.log(bakedText);
  }
})(text);
```

See demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/H4DpV/